# Using a custom animation with MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, mbprogresshud

Has anyone here tried to use a custom animation with MBProgressHUD. There is a custom view option but it's only for a somewhat static display that you've completed a task. I'm looking for a way to replace the spinning spokes with, for example, a spinning beach ball or some other graphic of my choosing. I've read thru the drawRect method in his source and am not familiar enough with drawing to see any mod I could make to accomplish my goal. I'm hoping someone here has done it and will share or that someone can point me in the right direction to help me do it myself.
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by creating a UIImageView that animates a set of images, and then setting the `customView` property of your MBProgressHUD to be that UIImageView.

Here's a tutorial about creating a UIImageView that animates the images:
[Create Custom Activity Indicator for your iOS App](http://web.archive.org/web/20120730005439/http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=336)

Comment: Thanks. I had seen the reference you linked to but didn't put 2 and 2 together to realize I could combine that with MBProgressHUD's customview property.